# Найти самую большую повторяющуюся подстроку в массиве

Tags: javascript, массивы, строки

Есть массив со строкой в котором нужно найти самую большую подстроку, которая повторяется.
Нельзя использовать готовые методы и функции строк.

> ["abcdgababcefbcdg"] - должно вернуть "bcdg".

Comment: а ваша попытка?

Comment: Пытался разделить строку по 4 элемента и искать совпадения, но так ни к чему не пришел, так как по условию задачи, длинна наибольшей подстроки не указывается.

Comment: Задача была, поищите

Comment: Как же работать со строкой, если "Нельзя использовать готовые методы и функции строк"?

Answer (score 0):

Объяснение алгоритма:

1. Сначала я прохожусь по всей строке и запоминаю для каждого уникального символа все индексы, где они встречаются, в массив
2. Объявляю пустую строку `maxRepeatedSubStr`, которая будет возвращена в самом конце
3. По очереди работаю со сформированными массивами. Если массив длины 1, то я его пропускаю, т.к. это означает, что в строке этот символ единнственный, а значит не может быть 2-х подстрок, которые начинаются с этого символа
4. В очередном массиве, перебираю всевозможные парные варианты индексов без повторений. Т.е. если я обработал пару `(0, 5)`, то уже `(5, 0)` не рассматриваю
5. Смотрю одинаковые ли символы находятся в строке в указанных индексах. Если да, то записваю этот символ в `repeatedSubStr` и "паралельно" сдвигаю индексы вправо, если нет, то сразу останавливаю цикл. Если нужны подстроки без пересечений, то ограничиваю первый индекс началом второго индекса, если нужны с пересечениями, то просто убираю эту проверку. Второй индекс, всегда ограничивается длиной строки, т.к. второй индекс всегда находится правее перового индекса
6. После окончания цикла проверяю является ли длина `repeatedSubStr` больше чем длина `maxRepeatedSubStr`. Если да, то `repeatedSubStr` становится новым `maxRepeatedSubStr`
7. И так далее пока я не переберу все массивы и всевозможные пары в них без повторений

Без пересечений:

```js
const findMaxRepeatedSubStr = (str) => {
  const lettersMap = new Map();

  for (let i = 0; i < str.length; ++i) {
    const letter = str[i];

    if (lettersMap.has(letter)) {
      lettersMap.get(letter).push(i);
    } else {
      lettersMap.set(letter, [i]);
    }
  }

  let maxRepeatedSubStr = '';

  for(const indexes of lettersMap.values()) {
    if (indexes.length === 1) continue;

    for (let i = 0; i < indexes.length; ++i) {
        for (let j = i + 1; j < indexes.length; ++j) {

          let firstIndex = indexes[i];
          let secondIndex = indexes[j];
          let repeatedSubStr = '';

          while (firstIndex < indexes[j] && secondIndex < str.length) {
            if (str[firstIndex] === str[secondIndex]) repeatedSubStr += str[firstIndex];
            else break;

            ++firstIndex;
            ++secondIndex;
          }

        if (repeatedSubStr.length > maxRepeatedSubStr.length) maxRepeatedSubStr = repeatedSubStr;
      }
    }
  }

  return maxRepeatedSubStr;
}


console.log([
  'abcdgababcefbcdg',
  'ababababab',
  'aaaa',
  'qwerty'
].map((str) => findMaxRepeatedSubStr(str)));
```

С перечесением:

```js
const findMaxRepeatedSubStr = (str) => {
  const lettersMap = new Map();

  for (let i = 0; i < str.length; ++i) {
    const letter = str[i];

    if (lettersMap.has(letter)) {
      lettersMap.get(letter).push(i);
    } else {
      lettersMap.set(letter, [i]);
    }
  }

  let maxRepeatedSubStr = '';

  for(const indexes of lettersMap.values()) {
    if (indexes.length === 1) continue;

    for (let i = 0; i < indexes.length; ++i) {
        for (let j = i + 1; j < indexes.length; ++j) {

          let firstIndex = indexes[i];
          let secondIndex = indexes[j];
          let repeatedSubStr = '';

          while (secondIndex < str.length) {
            if (str[firstIndex] === str[secondIndex]) repeatedSubStr += str[firstIndex];
            else break;

            ++firstIndex;
            ++secondIndex;
          }

        if (repeatedSubStr.length > maxRepeatedSubStr.length) maxRepeatedSubStr = repeatedSubStr;
      }
    }
  }

  return maxRepeatedSubStr;
}


console.log([
  'abcdgababcefbcdg',
  'ababababab',
  'aaaa',
  'qwerty'
].map((str) => findMaxRepeatedSubStr(str)));
```